# Where are tutorials for DotNetOpenAuth and how to solve compile error in its samples

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, dotnetopenauth

I know stackoverflow uses OpenID authentication. I want to try and use this as well. I am using asp.net mvc 2.0 with C#.

I found this

http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

and I am wondering if this is what was used for stackoverflow.

Also any tutorials would be nice as well.

Edit

I am trying to load up some sample projects but when I build it in VS2010 I get

```
Error   6   'System.Diagnostics.Contracts.ContractInvariantMethodAttribute' is inaccessible due to its protection level C:\Users\chobo2\Downloads\DotNetOpenAuth-3.4.6.10357\DotNetOpenAuth-3.4.6.10357\Samples\OpenIdOfflineProvider\TextBoxTextWriter.cs  73  4   OpenIdOfflineProvider
Error   7   The type or namespace name 'ContractInvariantMethod' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\chobo2\Downloads\DotNetOpenAuth-3.4.6.10357\DotNetOpenAuth-3.4.6.10357\Samples\OpenIdOfflineProvider\TextBoxTextWriter.cs  73  4   OpenIdOfflineProvider
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is the library SO uses. See [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/openid-one-year-later/) blog post from Jeff:

> we have an excellent dialog with Andrew Arnott, the primary author of the open source DotNetOpenAuth library we use.

The download includes samples.

Comment: It's also *so* very easy to use!

Comment: @chobo2 - Have you added a reference to the assembly mentioned? You need to have code contracts installed.

Comment: System.Diagnostics seems to be part of the system .dll

Comment: @chobo2 - You are right. Perhaps they are expecting a different version :(

Comment: Not sure what version though. system.dll is like version 2.0

Comment: Hmmm... I probably shouldn't have made that sample take a dependency on Code Contracts.  However, if you're interested in making a web site that uses OpenID, you can ignore that sample (Unload it in VS2010 to stop the build errors) and look at the web-based RP samples.

Comment: @chobo2 - See the comment from @Andrew Arnott, above - one sample depends on code contracts, but if you unload that project, you should be able to build the other samples without a problem.

Comment: @Andrew Arnott - Which project has the code contracts? Also what is the web-based Rp samples?

Comment: The build error should tell you which project it is for sure, but I think it's the OpenIDOfflineProvider project.  The web-based RP samples are OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms and OpenIdRelyingPartyMvc.

Answer (score 11):

I have just found this [tutorial](http://scatteredcode.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/dotnetopenauth-oauth-and-mvc-for-dummies/) which is useful.

Edit: [This one](http://blog.techcle.com/2010/03/20/simple-oauth-integration-for-twitter-in-asp-net-mvc/) also looks worth a read.

And I also found [this example useful](http://weblogs.asp.net/haithamkhedre/archive/2011/03/13/openid-authentication-with-asp-net-mvc3-dotnetopenauth-and-openid-selector.aspx).

Answer (score 8):

Far too many things to comment, as suggested by Alex Angas. Best to just install the dependency, it's not included by default with .NET.

Code Contracts: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/

Comment: This link above was not working for me, so I found the correct link here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/dd491992.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the update, now linking directly to their research page instead. Which has the proper download link to your page.

Answer (score 1):

[DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/) is a trustworthy choice.

To fix the build errors, comment out all references to `Contract(...)` in the code. They're only there to help the developers ensure code correctness and don't provide any functionality.